# How to get Salesforce username using REST api?

Tags: python, rest, python-2.7, salesforce

I am using web server flow for oAuth and simple-salesforce REST api to login the user using the access token and instance url. I have gone through the http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm documentation and coudn't find anything on it.

Comment: Everything's explained [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/quickstart_oauth.htm), is it not enough?

Comment: @SébastienDeprez how do I get the Salesforce username of the user who logged in using oAuth?

Comment: I'm not sure what data do you have/use. Are you making the oAuth yourself?

Comment: @SébastienDeprez no i am using this https://github.com/neworganizing/salesforce-oauth2 to get the access and refresh tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment saying you're using https://github.com/neworganizing/salesforce-oauth2 : you can do something like :

```
import urllib 

# After you get the code
response = salesforce_oauth_2.get_token(code)
print urllib.urlopen(response['id'])
```

The json object response returned by `get_token` should contain an `id` attribute which is an url that you can query for more information about the current user. See [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) for more details (paragraph 5).

Answer (score 0):

Get your salesforce dev to write a simple method that when pinged returns the context user details that you're after. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST) for an example.